# Using OWIN ApiController and AspNet ControllerBase with a common API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, owin, ioc-container

I have a requirement to add an HTTP REST api to an application that will need to run on .net framework 4.7.2 as well as .net core. The core logic is targeting .net standard 2.0 and uses autofac for dependency injection. I’m planning to use OWIN for the framework dependent build and aspnet webApi for the core build.

Ideally I would like to create common API controllers used by both applications. I can certainly inject services into the different controller types but that would get hard to maintain long term and tough to catch mismatched routes etc. I could probably also just use OWIN everywhere and not leverage aspnet core but don’t want to, the framework build will probably have a 2yr requirement before I no longer need to maintain it and would prefer aspnet webApi long term.

Is there a way to add ApiControllers to an aspnet core application or abstract between the two?

Currently I’ve only been able to inject common services with APIs into the two different controller types to accomplish my required results.

Example Injectable Service with Api:

**Main library containing services target .Net Standard 2.0**

```
public interface IDebuggingLevelUtility
{
    LogEventLevel Level { get; }
    void ChangeDebugLevel(LogEventLevel loggingLevel);
}
```

**Example of an Api ControllerBase hosted in a .net Core WebApi Application**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/debugging")]
public class DebuggingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<DebuggingController> _logger;
    private readonly IDebuggingLevelUtility _debugging;

    public DebuggingController(ILogger<DebuggingController> logger, IDebuggingLevelUtility debugging)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _debugging = debugging;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> GetLoggerLevel()
    {
        try
        {
            return _debugging.Level.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to change logging Level");
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("{level}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(BadRequestResult), 500)]
    public  ActionResult<string> PostLoggerLevel(LogEventLevel level)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Changing debugging level from {current} => {new}", LoggingLevel.Level.MinimumLevel, level);
            _debugging.ChangeDebugLevel(level);
            return _debugging.Level.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to change logging Level");
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Example ApiController hosted in a .Net Framework 4.7.2 application using OWIN self hosted

```
[RoutePrefix("api/debugging")]
public class DebuggingController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IDebuggingLevelUtility _debuggingLevelUtility;

    public DebuggingController(ILogger logger, IDebuggingLevelUtility debuggingLevelUtility)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _debuggingLevelUtility = debuggingLevelUtility;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public void GetLoggerLevel()
    {
        //DONT WANT TO CREATE CONTROLLERS TWICE
    }...
}
```

Ideally I would abstract the two controllers and create my custom Api Route Handlers centrally located.  I believe these use source generators so I'm not entirely sure where to be begin.  Ideally I have "MySuperCoolApiController" and inject the required services.  This ApiController can be mapped to both the OWIN self hosted api and the AspNet core WebApi. Hope this provide some better clarity.

Comment: Can you describe it in more detail? It would be better if some code or structure can be provided.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  I provided some examples for clarity.